# Is it possible to theme the node editor panel to be transparent?

Tags: node-editor, interface

I've been in the node editor a lot recently and noticed that I often want to use the N panel for naming nodes etc. but it takes up a lot of screen space. The N panel in the Viewport is transparent where there is no UI, but I can't figure out if there is a way to achieve this in the node editor too. Is there a setting to do this somewhere?

[image: e]